# SQL Function for adding dates

Tags: mysql, sql

How to create a function in SQL by adding 7 days to the current date and return through the function i will pass a date to the function which starts from date monday and i want to add 7 days to that date i.e one week.in the function i want to check whether the date is a valid date or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Date_Add()` to do this.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @McDowell Yes, but "Use Date_Add" is too short.

Answer (score 0):

For quite some time now, date arithmetic in MySQL can be performed using a simple `+`, like this:

```
SELECT date_col + INTERVAL 1 WEEK FROM …
```

If you prefer days over weeks, you can also write `+ INTERVAL 7 DAY`, i.e. using the singular unit name.

I cannot imagine what you mean by *“check whether the date is a valid date or not”,* as for every valid date, the date one week after is valid as well.

See also [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b7c7/10) for a working example. The fact that the simple date gets printed including time and timezone appears to be an artefact of the HTML rendering, the actual value is a date only, as the cast to string shows.